# Compile Pybind with header files in Makefile (not using cmake)

Tags: c++, makefile, compilation, header-files, pybind11

I am trying to compile a `Pybind11` module in `C++` which calls several header files `(.h)` on top. As I have a lot of header files, I decided to do a `Makefile`, which works without problem, EXCEPT for creating the target shared object file `(s.o)`. I need this shared object file in order to be able to call the Pybind module in Python.

However, when compiling, I get:

```
g++ -shared -fPIC neat.o network.o nnode.o link.o trait.o gene.o innovation.o organism.o species.o genome.o population.o example.o -o example.so
/usr/bin/ld: example.o: relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `_ZTI3Pet' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:2: recipe for target 'example.so' failed
make: *** [example.so] Error 1
```

My question is basically: What I am doing wrong when compiling the object files in order to create a target ?

**Makefile**

```
example.so: neat.o network.o nnode.o link.o trait.o gene.o innovation.o organism.o species.o genome.o population.o example.o
    g++ neat.o network.o nnode.o link.o trait.o gene.o innovation.o organism.o species.o genome.o population.o example.o -shared -o example.so

neat.o: neat.cpp neat.h
    g++ -c -O3 -Wall -fPIC neat.cpp

network.o: network.cpp network.h
    g++ -c -O3 -Wall -fPIC network.cpp

nnode.o: nnode.cpp nnode.h
    g++ -c -O3 -Wall -fPIC nnode.cpp

link.o: link.cpp link.h
    g++ -c -O3 -Wall -fPIC link.cpp

trait.o: trait.cpp trait.h
    g++ -c -O3 -Wall -fPIC trait.cpp

gene.o: gene.cpp gene.h
    g++ -c -O3 -Wall -fPIC gene.cpp

innovation.o: innovation.cpp innovation.h
    g++ -c -O3 -Wall -fPIC innovation.cpp

organism.o: organism.cpp organism.h genome.h genome.cpp species.h species.cpp
    g++ -c -O3 -Wall -fPIC organism.cpp

species.o: species.h species.cpp organism.cpp organism.h genome.h genome.cpp
    g++ -c -O3 -Wall -fPIC species.cpp

genome.o: genome.cpp genome.h
    g++ -c -O3 -Wall -fPIC genome.cpp

population.o: population.cpp population.h organism.h
    g++ -c -O3 -Wall -fPIC population.cpp

experiments.o: experiments.cpp experiments.h
    g++ -c -O3 -Wall -fPIC experiments.cpp

example.o:
    g++ -O3 -Wall -std=c++11 -fopenmp -I -fPIC `python3 -m pybind11 --includes` -c example.cpp

clean:
    rm *.o *.so
```

**example.cpp**

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "population.h"

namespace py = pybind11;

int create_neat(){
  Population *the_pop=0;
  return 0;
}
PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m){

  m.def("create_neat", &create_neat, "create a pop object");

}
```

Comment: We can't help because you haven't shown us any of the actual errors.  The statement `recipe for target ... failed` is just make telling you that your link failed.  To know _why_ it failed you have to show us the errors generated by your linker (that will come before this message).

Comment: Well sure: you can't execute an object file.  An object file is not a program.  You can't execute a shared library either.  A shared library is not a program.

Comment: You need to add `-fPIC` to _ALL_ your compile lines, if you want to link those objects into a shared library.

Comment: Again, thank you for your response. I don't want to abuse your patience but it still doesn't work. I am not sure about what you mean with `compile lines`, if my understanding is correct, you mean all compilation lines of the object files, in order to link those with a shared library which will be the shared object file

Comment: I have also tried adding the -I flag but it won't help. The error is always the same as before

Comment: I think you need to find a tutorial on the basic operation of compiling and linking, and what the standard options are for compiling code.  Not sure if SO is the right place, but if it is you should be asking individual targeted questions.  This question has gone well past its original life.  You have made many many changes to the question and it's no longer clear what the current problem is you're trying to solve.

Comment: The issue of _can't execute example.o_ I already explained: you can't do that because you can't execute object files.  Object files are not programs.  The issue of incorrect linking will be solved by adding `-fPIC` to the compile recipes.  Yes, the compile recipes are the recipes that build `.o` files (turning a source file into an object file is called _compiling_ the source file).  If you are still seeing that error be sure you've cleaned all the old `.o` files before running make with the new flags.

Comment: Adding `-I` only helps you find include files so that will only help if you're getting errors about not being able to find header files.

Comment: The issue concerning the execution of the `.o`file is clear since you explained it. I just didn't pay attention to remove it. I have done what you explained: add `-I`, add `fPIC`, clean `.o` files, and still, also since you explained it... Nothing changes. I am indeed looking at tutorials but still, I don't manage to find where is the error...

Comment: Anyway thanks for your time

Comment: It worked ! see answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several hours of reading, trying, and also thanks to the hints of MadScientist, I got it working but the reasons why are still unclear. I just changed the order of the prerequisites in the compilation of the target, by putting the `-shared -o example.so` in front and not at the end of the line, and it worked. 
The whole file is as follows:

```
example.so: neat.o network.o nnode.o link.o trait.o gene.o innovation.o organism.o species.o genome.o population.o example.o
    g++ -shared -o example.so neat.o network.o nnode.o link.o trait.o gene.o innovation.o organism.o species.o genome.o population.o example.o

neat.o: neat.cpp neat.h
    g++ -c -O3 -Wall -fPIC neat.cpp

network.o: network.cpp network.h
    g++ -c -O3 -Wall -fPIC network.cpp

nnode.o: nnode.cpp nnode.h
    g++ -c -O3 -Wall -fPIC nnode.cpp

link.o: link.cpp link.h
    g++ -c -O3 -Wall -fPIC link.cpp

trait.o: trait.cpp trait.h
    g++ -c -O3 -Wall -fPIC trait.cpp

gene.o: gene.cpp gene.h
    g++ -c -O3 -Wall -fPIC gene.cpp

innovation.o: innovation.cpp innovation.h
    g++ -c -O3 -Wall -fPIC innovation.cpp

organism.o: organism.cpp organism.h genome.h genome.cpp species.h species.cpp
    g++ -c -O3 -Wall -fPIC organism.cpp

species.o: species.h species.cpp organism.cpp organism.h genome.h genome.cpp
    g++ -c -O3 -Wall -fPIC species.cpp

genome.o: genome.cpp genome.h
    g++ -c -O3 -Wall -fPIC genome.cpp

population.o: population.cpp population.h organism.h
    g++ -c -O3 -Wall -fPIC population.cpp

experiments.o: experiments.cpp experiments.h
    g++ -c -O3 -Wall -fPIC experiments.cpp

example.o:
    g++ -O3 -Wall -std=c++11 -fopenmp `python3 -m pybind11 --includes` -fPIC -c example.cpp

clean:
    rm *.o *.so
```

Answer (score 1):

The standard doesn't completely define the difference between `#include "..."` and `#include <...>`, but in all compilers I'm familiar with the `<>` syntax for include typically means, "this is a system-type header file" and the `""` syntax means "this is a local-type header file".

In practice this usually means that `""` are looked for in the working directory, then in directories specified by `-I` options to the compiler and finally in system default directories, while `<>` is the same except it does not look in the working directory.

So, you either need to change your code to use:

```
#include "population.h"
```

or else you need to add `-I.` to your compile line so the compiler knows to look in the current directory:

```
population.o: population.cpp population.h organism.h
        g++ -I. -c population.cpp
```

Personally I would do both, because it's good hygiene to add the directories you need to your compile line, and because it's good practice to use `""` for local headers so people reading the code understand immediately that this is your header and not a system header.

For your second question, *Is the compilation in order to make a shared object file with the object files correct* I'm sorry but I don't understand what you're asking.

If you're asking about the order of targets defined in the makefile, then they can be in any order at all *except* that the first target will be the default target (if you run `make` with no target name then make will build the first target--and any prerequisites needed for the first target).

*ETA*

OK, now that we can see that the actual error is that `example.o` does not exist.  Why does it not exist?  Again, because you've removed important details from the example in your question we can't say for sure.  When you write in your question:

```
example.so: //some .o files which are not important// HERE IS THE PROBLEM
```

what exactly are the `.o` files that appear as prerequisites of `example.so`?

You must list the file `example.o` as a prerequisite of `example.so` if you want make to build `example.o` before trying to build `example.so`.  You need to list *all* the object files that are needed to create the shared library.  So this should be:

```
example.so: population.o example.o neat.o network.o nnode.o link.o trait.o gene.o innovation.o organism.o species.o genome.o
```

It doesn't matter what order they appear in the prerequisites list, but they must all be there.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This was perhaps part of the issue. I have updated the code but I am still unable to build the shared object file. I have updated the error

Comment: As above, we can't know for sure without seeing the error messages from the linker.  However, I'll venture a guess that you forgot to add the `-fPIC` option to the compile line (the recipe creating the `.o` files); that's where it's needed.

Comment: Ok, so I have updated the error message. What I meant with "Is the compilation in order to make a shared object file with the object files correct" was: "are the flags correct" ? Because it is not clear where I should put the flags: weather in the compilation for the shared object file, or the for the object file. Please tell me if something else remains unclear. If I undestand correctly, -fPIC is related with the creation of the object file. This is already something. I have updated the code this way

Comment: I have added the whole compilation object files,  ordered in a way that all the prerequisited header files in each of the `.cpp` files compile before calling the constructor. The `population.h` header file calls `innovation.h, genome.h species.h organism.h`. Again, please tell me if something is missing. I really thought not specifying the whole files was ok, as the makefile works perfectly without calling some Pybind

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "before calling the constructor", and how a header file "calls" another header file.  Do you mean, _includes_ another header file?  Constructors are part of C++ code, they don't have anything to do with the compile line or the makefile.

Comment: The immediate problem I see with your makefile is that in the prerequisites list for `example.so` you list an object file `experiments.o` but in the link line in the recipe you list an object file `example.o`.  If you need both of them you need to put both of them in the prerequisites list _AND_ in the link line.  Usually you would not duplicate these to avoid these kinds of errors, but instead use an _automatic variable_ (in this case, *$^*) in the recipe which expands to "all the prerequisite files".

Comment: By before "calling the constructor", I mean that the compilation of the `.o` files is done according to the order of the calls to the header files. Like for example, `neat.o` doesn't call any header file, but network does call the header file `neat.h` therefore I put it after. I am not sure if this is really relevant, but I just did it for having it clear, and also not doing it was causing me some errors.

Comment: Concerning the recipe, you are right. Actually I was misunderstanding the role of those prerequisites for the target. I thought they had the same role as the ones for compiling the `.o` files. Now, the compilation of the `example.o` file works, but not the compilation of the target. I get an error which I have never seen before which is: `/usr/bin/ld: example.o: relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `_ZTI3Pet' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: So I have compiled with fPIC but still get the same error. I am currently looking where does it come from and have updated the question